# How can i get the clicked button's row values on silverlight telerik radgridview button column?

Tags: silverlight, telerik

I have a hyperlink button colum in silverlight telerik radgridview, as a cell template.
I am using MVVM.
When i click on the hyperlink button, how can i get its row's values(atleast in the code behind)..?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ParentOfType extension method to get hold of the row containing the button.

Once you have the row you can cast the item type to your viewmodel and access the properties of it.

Make sure you have a using statement for the extension method:

```
using Telerik.Windows.Controls;  


 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var parent = (sender as Button).ParentOfType<GridViewRow>();
    var rowVM = parent.Item as YourVmClass;
}
```

If you are using MVVM you can also use the EventToCommandBehavior. 
This allows you to execute all events as commands. You can then handle the command in your viewmodel.